# Creating embedded app in Yammer

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to create an App that has an embedded page (iframe/etc) inside Yammer ?

- Looks like the apps are only able to manipulate Yammer from outside (Open Graph) but can't actually be pages inside Yammer

(Similar to apps in facebook)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yammer doesn't have third-party app running inside users' home page/feed.  However Apps can be listed under Yammer Directory and users can go from their menu inside Yammer to browse the apps and use them.  Existing apps can be found at: https://www.yammer.com/apps?from=nav